# How to convert data nvarchar to float when updating SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to convert `nvarchar` data to float when updating in SQL Server?

```
@nilai_ahir = 6,000,000.00

SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "update thetable set nilai_ahir=@nilai_ahir where idrec=@idrec"
```

when executing the `SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand`, I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: Really, you should be declaring `@nilai_ahir` as a `float`, not a `nvarchar` (numbers don't even any non-ASCII characters, so an `nvarchar` makes little sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REPLACE` with `CONVERT` will work in your case:

```
update thetable set nilai_ahir= CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE(@nilai_ahir, ',', '')) where idrec=@idrec
```

`REPLACE` used to remove the commas from the string and it will result as `6000000.00` then it easy to `CONVERT` as `FLOAT`.